# javascript changing value of form element and socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have the following code that works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function loaded(){
    oFormElement = document.forms['test form'].elements["txtStatus"];
    oFormElement.value = "just loaded";

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="loaded()">
<p>my first socket.io test</p>
<form id = "test form">
<input type="text" id ="txtStatus" value="">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

now, if I include the reference to socket.io, it stops working

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js">
<script>

function loaded(){
```

is this because socket.io handles from elements in it's own way, or is because the browser cannot find socket.io ? Is there any way to debug this/fix this ?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted by clicking the hollow check mark to the left of the answer, rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also upvote the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the first `<script>` tag...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

function loaded(){

   // ...
```